# XSLT: Disable output escaping in an entire document

Tags: .net, xslt, code-generation

I'm trying to generate some C# code using xslt - its working great until I get to generics and need to output some text like this:

```
MyClass<Type>
```

In this case I've found that the only way to emit this is to do the following:

```
MyClass<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>Type<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Where:

- Often it all needs to go on one line, otherwise you end up with line breaks in the generated code
- In the above example I technically could have used only 1 `<xsl:text />`, however usually the type `Type` is given by some other template, e.g:

`<xsl:value-of select="@type" />`

I don't mind having to write `&lt;` a lot, but I would like to avoid writing `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>` for just a single character!

Is there any way of doing `disable-output-escaping="yes"` for the entire document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this wasn't working was all down to the I was applying the transform - I was using a XslCompiledTransform and an XmlWriter to transform my xml, however according to [Microsoft XML Teams blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/articles/Introducing_XslCompiledTransform.aspx) as soon as I use an XmlWriter to write my output the  tag is ignored!

I fixed this by explicitly setting the XmlWriters output settings to those of the Xsl transform:

```
XmlWriterSettings ws = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
ws.CheckCharacters = false;

xslt.Transform("MyDocument.xml", XmlWriter.Create(Console.Out, ws));
```

Once I did this, the transform respected my  tag, and all was well!

Answer (score 1):

> its working great until I get to
>   generics and need to output some text
>   like this:
>
> ```
> MyClass<Type>
> ```
>
> In this case I've found that the
>   only way to emit this is to do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> MyClass<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>Type<xsl:text
> ```
>
> disable-output-escaping="yes">>

**Certainly, this is *not* the only way and this is the worst way to produce such result**.

> Is there any way of doing
>   disable-output-escaping="yes" for the
>   entire document?

**This is what the `method="text"` attribute of `<xsl:output>` is for. No need of DOE**.

So, use the `tex`t output method and then:

```
 MyClass&lt;Type>
```

**Here is a complete small example**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  MyClass&lt;Type>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced**:

```
  MyClass<Type>
```

I am the author of the XPath Visualizer, which produces IE-like presentation of XML files -- nowhere in thie code there is any DOE.

Comment: I already have `<xsl:output method="text" />` in my XSLT, but it makes no difference - is it possible I'm calling my XSLT processor incorrectly?

Comment: @Kragen: I updated the answer to give you a complete example how to generate the desired text without DOE.

Comment: Thanks - I have no idea why I thought it wasn't working, but this seems to work for me now.

Comment: Ah! Just figured out why this wasn't working! - See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is NOT a direct answer of your question but.

Huge assumption here: you have somthing like:

```
<classthing class="MyClass" type="atype"/>
```

You could call a template:

```
 <xsl:template match="classthing">
    <xsl:call-template name="setgeneric">
      <xsl:with-param name="myclass"><xsl:value-of select="@class" /></xsl:with-param>
      <xsl:with-param name="mytype"><xsl:value-of select="@type" /></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="setgeneric">
    <xsl:param name="myclass" />
    <xsl:param name="mytype" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$myclass"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$mytype"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```